# Android - Checkbox centering and filling layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox, android-linearlayout

I have a spinner which has an item template. Inside I have a textview and a checkbox that fills the layout, but it is fixed at left border (see image). How do I make checkbox centered, while not wrapping it's content? Padding and margins don't work.

[Link to checkbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z80AC.png)

Item template layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/location_item_dash"
            android:foreground="#000"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            local:MvxBind="Text LocationName"
            android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8" />
        <CheckBox
            local:MvxBind="Checked Selected"
            android:background="@drawable/location_item_dash"
            android:id="@+id/spinnercheck"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: dont get what you want.

Comment: I would like it exactly the same, but checkbox in the middle

Comment: And what about text ?

Comment: Text is okay, checkbox is the only thing to change

Comment: User RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your checkbox inside another layout and use center gravity in outer layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/location_item_dash"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:foreground="#000"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        local:MvxBind="Text LocationName" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/spinnercheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/location_item_dash"
            android:gravity="center"
            local:MvxBind="Checked Selected" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can make it centered while wrapping content, but it needs to fill the layout

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet? I am facing same issue. Very frustrating , checkbox border is not filling the layout completely